# improving the quality of view after adding a shadow to it

Tags: ios, view, swift3, xcode8, shadow

#### I've added a dropshadow to a view in my tableview cell but all the content of that cell has now really bad quality

Here's the code I've used to create the shadow:

```
    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPVMB.png)

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you very much, I appreciate any kind of help

Comment: can you post images?

Comment: @DishantKapadiya you can see even the text is a little pixelated. I've already tried it on my iPhone and it's still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what I did wrong:

I accidentally set the `shouldRasterize` property to true instead of false.

Maybe this helps someone else too